# Hysterix Javanica AsyncResult Future.get Throwing Exception

Tags: java, hystrix, spring-cloud-netflix

I have a Spring Cloud set up running on my local tomcat. I am using feign client to invoke a remote service wrapped inside Hysterix command one direct and other async as below.

```
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "fallBackEmployeeCall")
    public List<EmployeeBean> getEmployees() {
        //Call through Feign Client
        return empInterface.getEmployees();
    }

    //Async Version
    @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "fallBackEmployeeCall")
public Future<List<EmployeeBean>> getEmployeesAsync() {
    return new AsyncResult<List<EmployeeBean>>() {
        @Override
        public List<EmployeeBean> invoke() {
            return empInterface.getEmployees();
        }
    };
}
```

When I am calling getEmployeesAsync().get()
I am getting below exception

**java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: AsyncResult is just a stab and cannot be used as complete implementation of Future**

It is similar to below issue :-

```
[https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/issues/1179][1]
```

According to docs the solution is to configure HystrixCommandAspect class, which I did as below :-

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class HystrixConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public HystrixCommandAspect hystrixAspect() {
        return new HystrixCommandAspect();
    }

}
```

But I am still getting the same exception. It seems I am missing some configuration.
Note :- my sync method is working fine.

Comment: Can you post the client code, where you are testing the invokations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try call `getEmployeesAsync` in the other class, which injected the instance of the class with `getEmployeesAsync`. I had this exception, too. Then I do it like this successful.

Comment: What difference will it make by calling it in another class? Can you elaborate?